# Jetpack Compose app bar actions no ripple effect

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, ripple-effect

I have an app bar in my application:

```kotlin
SmallTopAppBar(
    title = { Text("✨StarDict✨") },
    actions = {
        IconButton(
            onClick = {...}
        ) {
            Icon(
                painterResource(R.drawable.ic_dict),
                tint = Color.White,
                contentDescription = "",
            )
        }

        IconButton(
            onClick = {...}
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Default.Settings,
                tint = Color.White,
                contentDescription = "",
            )
        }

        IconButton(
            onClick = {...}
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Default.Info,
                tint = Color.White,
                contentDescription = "",
            )
        }
    },
    colors = colors,
)
```

However, the action buttons don't have a ripple effect. All other buttons do, but not the action buttons in the app bar.

Is there a way to add the ripple effect?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried instead of using `IconButton`, just using `Icon` with `Modifier.clickable {}`? I usually just do that and it adds the ripple by default.

Comment: @hahmraro Unfortunately, it doesn't work.